# Question about sql selection and print_r array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a question, first look my code:

```
$testsql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM forum_sujets');
$testsql->execute();
$test = $testsql->fetch();
print_r($test);
```

My DB:

[image]

Ok, so I want to select my information in array, and i wan't this array look like:

```
array(              
    'id' => '1', array(
        'nom' => 'test',
        'titre' => 'test',
        'auteur' => 'test',
    ),
    'id' => '2', array(
        'nom' => 'test2',
        'titre' => 'test2',
        'auteur' => 'test2',
    ),
 );
```

Ok, and after my array look like this, I want to echo, for exemple, the name of the ID "2", I don't known if i'm clearful. I hope you can help me, see u :)

Comment: did you try `foreach loop` ?

Comment: If you need information about id = 2 then use `WHERE id = 2` in your query.

Comment: Also, provided array structure is __invalid__, you can not have more than one `id` key on same level of array.

Comment: Yes, i already put my request in a while but for optimization i wan't to put it outside of the while and in the while call necessary information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, your screenshot is not so good so I suppose you have colums titre, nom et auteur dans votre table:

```
$testsql = $db->prepare('SELECT id, titre, nom, auteur FROM forum_sujets');
$testsql->execute();
$data = [];
while ($test = $testsql->fetch()) {
    $id = $test['id'];
    $data[$id] = [
        'nom' => $test['nom'],
        'auteur' => $test['auteur'],
        'title' => $test['title'],
    ];
}

print_r($data);
```

The output will be like :

```
array(              
    1 => array(
        'nom' => 'test',
        'titre' => 'test',
        'auteur' => 'test',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'nom' => 'test2',
        'titre' => 'test2',
        'auteur' => 'test2',
    ),
 );
```

As you cannot have two same key in one array

Comment: Good one. I only wanted to note that @u_mulder is probably right in his comment above that BaguetteV1.0 is actually looking for just one record. So using WHERE clause might be a better approach. But we can't be sure unless it's explained further how the whole code works and what is it good for.